# How to set a customized and editable start menu layout using PowerShell on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, start-menu, xml

I'm trying to set a *flexible* initial start layout for new users by running a PowerShell script after setting up their accounts. I *can't* enforce this through group policies because it wouldn't allow users to customize their start menus afterwards.

I've already tried this command:

```
Import-StartLayout –LayoutPath c:\Temp\LayoutModification.xml –MountPath C:\
```

However the new start layout would be only visible for *new user accounts* that are created on this PC after I run this command.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Workaround: third-party tools such as Classic Shell (http://www.classicshell.net/) or its successors allow exporting and importing the layout and other customization as XML.

Comment: Why are you not just using a startup / logon or RunOnce script for new users.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'll take a look to this third-party tool to see if it works. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: @postanote That's what I'm trying to do. Could you provide some code sample so I can give you the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading this.

You are try to change the layout for any existing users and all new users?

Why?

I get it for new users, you have that with this approach (that is what it does by design), but for existing users?

Why mess up what they already have in place?

I'd be seriously PO'd if my IT team did this. People spend a lot of time setting the desktops.

Are you sure you want that backlash?

The simplest / sure way to deal with this on workstations / servers, it to delete the all user profiles, and allow the default profile to be used and thus recreate the profile on first log as normal, since this is part of their profile, among other things.

You can do this, without the profile delete using this approach.

> https://lazyadmin.nl/it/update-change-start-menu-layout-windows-10-pro-for-existing-users

BTW, you could still do this via GPO, force an update in the enterprise, then remove the GPO, which would thus give control back to the users.